# You would get sick

Tags: grammaticality

Q: if you take this medicine, what happens?

Are the following answer all correct?

1. You **will get** sick.
2. You **get** sick.
3. You **can get** sick.
4. You **would get** sick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. If you take this medicine, you will get sick

This is correct. If you take this medicine right now, sometime in the future you will definitely get sick.

> 2. If you take this medicine, you get sick.

This just about works as a general statement: if, at any time, you were to take this medicine, then at some time later you would get sick. A better example of a general statement would be

> If you take drugs, you get sick.

.

> 3. If you take this medicine, you can get sick.

The possible meanings of [can](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can) are ability, permission, request, possibility and offer: none of these really work possibility sounds like it might work, but the meaning is closer to ability than to probability. [Could](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could) would work, as it can be *used to express possibility, especially slight or uncertain possibility*

> 4. If you take this medicine, you would get sick.

If you use [would](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) with **if**, it implies a hypothetical situation so you have to put the verb in the past:

> If you **took** this medicine, you would get sick.

Answer (score 1):

> If you take this medicine.

goes with

> You will get sick.  *(in the future, after taking the medicine)*
>   You get sick.  *(will is left out but implied)*
>   You can get sick. *(hypothetical future situation)*

Your other answer

> You would get sick.

goes with

> If you took this medicine.